# How can I find a postal_code for a given Lat/Lon in a OSM database?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, gps

I have a OSM database on postgres/postGIS. Data are downloaded from https://download.geofabrik.de/ and created in postgres with osm2pgsql using schema osm2pgsql.

Now I'm looking for a postalcode on a given GPS position. How can I find this in the OSM database?

Comment: You didn't mention which database schema you are using. Tools such as osm2pgsql,  imposm, ogr ... create different database schema, so the SQL is different. Have a look to https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases_and_data_access_APIs#Database_Schemas

Comment: Also, the concept of finding a postal code for a geolocation is highly country specific, and doesn't even apply at all in some cases. Then there's the question of coverage in the OSM data. It would be better to rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: Right! I used this only for germany:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Query is i.e.:

```
SELECT tags->'postal_code', tags, st_asgeojson(way) 
FROM planet_polygon 
WHERE boundary = 'postal_code' AND 
ST_Contains(way, ST_Transform( ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.5830 48.7657)', 4326), 900913))
```

The query search over all 'postal_code' polygons and find the matching post_code (in German PLZ = Postleitzahl)